# Disable Auto-start Application

Tags: startup, autostart

I couple of versions of Ubuntu ago I setup a program to start automatically when the computer turns on.  It is of no use to me at this point, and I want to disable it now.  The problem is, I can't figure out how I did it.  I've looked in:

- Startup Applications (`gnome-session-properties`)
- ~/.config/autostart
- ~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session/
- /etc/init.d/
- /etc/gdm/

Is there somewhere else I might have set it?  Or is there a way to trace how a running program was started?  Couldn't find anything like that in System Monitor.

Comment: what is the application?

Comment: @Achu: The program is an on-screen keyboard: `onboard`

Comment: Have you looked at gnome-session-properties ?

Comment: @desgua: I don't think so, where is that?

Comment: You can access the gnome-session-properties by pressing alt+f2 and typing in gnome-session-properties

Comment: @Gus: oh, Startup Applications.  Yeah, I checked it.

Comment: Have you looked at scripts at /etc/gdm/ ?

Comment: @desgua: Yup, checked that just now.

Comment: Can you also check: /etc/inittab ; /etc/rc.local ; /etc/rc2.d ?

Comment: Then, if no luck,you could install BUM and see what we get from it...

Comment: Did you check ~/.xprofile, ~/.xsession, ~/.xinitrc?

Comment: @desgua: okay, I'll try that.

Comment: @nandhp: yup, nothing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `grep` it:

```
sudo grep -IRF onboard /etc 2> /dev/null
```

and if unsuccessful

```
grep -lIRF onboard ~/.[^.]* 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: The second one (sans the `2> /dev/null` part, because I wanted to see _where_ it was) turned up two results: `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-settings/gedit/%gconf.xml` and `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/applications/at/%gconf.xml`.  Removing the `onboard` bit fixed the problem.  There's no way I would have known about those files: what program could have set those entries?

Comment: Isn't it one of those accessibility thingies? http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#accessibilityconfiguration

Comment: I don't know.  I just hope it's safe to remove the code, and it's not actually supposed to be left alone and is called by the _actual_ setting... .  In any case, I only commented it out, I didn't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this GUI existed 11 years ago, but on Ubuntu 22.04 you have `gnome-session-properties` you can open from a terminal or open Startup Applications via the Activities overview.

[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en)