# Temporarily disable startup apps on login

Tags: 20.04, login, startup, ubuntu-gnome, autostart

How temporarily disable startup applications per a particular session at login in Ubuntu/Gnome?
Looking for the feature similar to Windows login when Shift key pressed until desktop starts.

Comment: does [this](https://sourcedigit.com/19004-how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-ubuntu/) help?

Comment: Thanks User24601 but I'm fully aware on how to manage startup applications. Actually, I interested in the way to disable all startups once for a particular session (once at login). I prefer to leave all startup configuration untouched for further logins/sessions.

Comment: so you mean creating a keyboard shortcut which if pressed at startup then all startup applications will be disabled temporally and if not then start as usual.

Comment: @preIdiot Yes, exactly.

Comment: yeah, that will be a cool feature. But I don't think it is available right now

Comment: Due to a complicating specific of autostarting in Linux/Ubuntu described here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/57098/disable-auto-start-application
 there is not that easy to disable startup apps in a clear transparent way.

Comment: You and me are both looking, buddy. I'm thinking of putting all mine in a single script and then it's only one thing to change to disable them.